# Redirect to Login page as opposed to pop-up Login in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WebAssembly app that uses Azure AD B2C for authentication.

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
});
```

When the user is redirected to authentication, Blazor display the login in a pop-up.

The problem with the pop-up is that the user could bury it if they clicked on the screen outside of the pop-up.

Wondering if there is a way to force the authentication to redirect to the page as opposed to displaying the pop-up.

Comment: Did you try to set `NavigateToLoginRequestUrl` to true ?

Comment: Hi @aguafrommars, where would that be done at?

Comment: In `options.ProviderOptions.Authentication` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.authentication.webassembly.msal.msalauthenticationoptions?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: K ... I don't think that it was I was looking for ... right now the Login works, it displays in a pop-up ... want it to display in a full page.

Comment: Yes, but did you try ?

Comment: You can also try using `AddOidcAuthentication` with same authority, clientId, scopes. It can work as AzureAd is an OAuth server.

Comment: I think you are correct, `AddOidcAuthentication` would work. Did hear back from the product team, and their response was "We do pop-up by default and redirect if the popup is blocked. We don't have an option to do redirect only."

Comment: Seems odd that this isn't possible. I too find the popup to be a bad way of doing it and would prefer a redirect instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To change from the pop-up page to a redirect you need:

```
options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "Redirect";
```

Comment: This worked for me.  The experience is a little jarring as it replaces the entire surface of the app with the login page.  I don't mind the popup, if it were modal.  Far too easy to click off of it and lose focus.  The average user would promptly be lost.