# Blazor WASM OIDC authentication with Microsoft identity provider

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to set up SSO with a Blazor WebAssmebly app (.NET 7).

On the Azure AD side of things, I have registered an application (SPA) with a login callback URI of `https://localhost/authentication/login-callback` .

I have disabled implicit and hybrid flows (unchecked Access and ID tokens). No other configuration of note.

On the app side of thigs, I have the following section in appsettings.json:

```
"AuthSettings": {
  "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/",
  "ClientId": "<my client id>",
  "ResponseType": "code"
}
```

In Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    // Configure your authentication provider options here.
    // For more information, see https://aka.ms/blazor-standalone-auth
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AuthSettings", options.ProviderOptions);
});
```

index.html has the

```
<script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js"></script>
```

line as well.

In general the setup is the standard one that comes with the Blazor WebAssembly VS project template when the Individual Accounts authentication type is selected.

When I log in with my Microsoft account, I get redirected to `/authentication/login-callback` , with a `code`, a `state`, and a `session_state`. I get a 200 response. A POST request is then sent to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token` with the code and other data, and I get an access, a refresh, and an ID token. So far so good.

Problem is, the frontend shows this:

```
There was an error trying to log you in: 'There was an error signing in.'
```

and I have no idea why. Everything seems to have worked perfectly so far.

I tried looking into the JS source for this message, and it looks like this function is the source, in AuthenticationService.js:

```
 async completeSignIn(t) {
                this.trace("completeSignIn", t);
                const e = await this.loginRequired(t)
                  , r = await this.stateExists(t);
                try {
                    const e = await this._userManager.signinCallback(t);
                    return window.self !== window.top ? this.operationCompleted() : (this.trace("completeSignIn-result", e),
                    this.success(e && e.state))
                } catch (t) {
                    return e || window.self !== window.top || !r ? this.operationCompleted() : this.error("There was an error signing in.")
                }
            }
```

but I have no idea how to debug this. I enabled trace logs in the console, but it just records the GET request to `login-callback`.

Any help please? Is it a configuration issue, or a bug? and how can I go about debugging it? I tried enabling debugging via the Chrome developer tools, but that's just another rabbit hole of issues.

**Has anyone been able to set up OIDC authentication with Microsoft accounts in Blazor WebAssembly?**

PS. I also tried MSAL, but that led into even more issues (e.g. popup windows that didn't close, etc. etc.). I tried Google OIDC as well, but, you guessed it, more issues -- I even raised [another question in SO about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77178632/blazor-wasm-oidc-authentication-issues-with-google-identity-provider).

All in all, I'm quite a bit disappointed with the state of Blazor authentication right now. I haven't been able to make this simple thing work for several days now. It's a basic, straightforward feature that most developers are going to need at some point, and honestly I would have expected this to work out of the box.

==============================================================

**UPDATE:**
I tried @Harshitha 's suggestion to set up MSAL via Visual Studio. Indeed, the experience was much smoother, by going to Connected Services and adding Microsoft identity platform.

It even worked once or twice, logging both my tenant user and my personal account!

BUT

after a couple of tries, I was faced with this:

[image: popup frozen]

i.e. after logging in, the popup is not closed, and the app is frozen. If I close the popup via the X button, I cannot click anything in my app window.

Looks like a javascript issue?

I can consistently reproduce it by logging in, logging out, and logging back in. The second login freezes as above.

**EDIT:** Interestingly, I could only reproduce the above while running the app with Debugging enabled (`F5`). I have made no changes to the original `launchSettings.json`

**EDIT 2:** I bypassed the above issue by setting LoginMode to "Redirect" in `AddMsalAuthentication`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64266153/3327031).

Comment: Same situation with a .NET 8 preview standard template, the only changes being setting the Authority to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common`, the ResponseType to `code` , and the client id to its proper value. => **There was an error signing in**.

Comment: Further updates -- I managed to set up Chrome debugging and debugged the .js file.

The exception in completeSignIn() is:
`Error: Invalid issuer in token: https://sts.windows.net/<my client id>/
    at t.validateJwtAttributes (https://localhost:7136/_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js:2:241879)
    at https://localhost:7136/_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js:2:61240`

Comment: Have you tried with Authentication Type Microsoft Identity Platform.It configures the complete code for you.

Comment: Hey @Harshitha , yes I did. It's a lot more pain to set up, including creating a separate tenant in AD, registering a new client flow, registering another identity provider, and so on and so forth.    
I did that nevertheless, but the end result was the same...  
Also, from what I understand, MSAL gives you the power to manage your app users in the AD tenant. I'm not really interested in that, I just want SSO authentication, and I will manage the roles locally in my app back-end.

Comment: No, In fact it is an easy way to configure Authentication.Select the authentication type as `Microsoft Identity Platform`. Add the same in Connected Services.No need to do any manual changes in the AAD. You can do everything from Visual Studio itself.

Comment: Interesting -- I will go try that and post here the results then. Thanks!

Comment: I will try to configure with .NET 8 Preview from my end and let you know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255436/discussion-between-spyros-and-harshitha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to configure Authentication with `Microsoft Identity Platform` for a .NET 8 Preview `Blazor WASM`.

***Check the below steps.***

- Select  `Microsoft Identity Platform`  Authentication Type .

[image]

- From the `Connected Services`, add the `Microsoft Identity platform` Service dependency.

[image]

- Login to the Azure Account Subscription.
- Select the correct tenant and create a new App registration.

[image]

[image]

- The below changes will be done in the Blazor App and Azure AD with the Microsoft Identity Platform configuration.

[image]

[image]

***My `appsettings.json`:***

```cs
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "ClientId": "************",
    "Authority": "https://login.*****.com/microsoft.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ValidateAuthority": true
  }
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did after your suggestion, and initially it worked! But then I ran into another issue (see update to the original question above for details and screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is fine. Looks like your fundamental problem may be related to the ID token validation that occurs before your app's library accepts received tokens. You may need to configure values such as an expected issuer.

Start by looking more closely at the ID token in a [JWT viewer](https://jwt.io) and understand its contents. See if there is a `nonce` field in the JWT header. If so then add an API scope to the OAuth client registration. [Steps 3 and 6 of my blog post](https://authguidance.com/azure-ad-troubleshooting/) provide further details.

Comment: It's quite probable. I focused mainly on making this work with MSAL, but I will try OIDC as well -- the `Invalid issuer in token` JS exception points that way too. I will look into this as well and update. Thanks for the tip!